# What does this mean in python? # In[1]

Tags: python, visual-studio

In visual studio I find that the comment code  `"# In [1]"` acts similar to the `#region` code in Visual Studio C# when using Python. The code `" # In [1] "` in python allows you to create expand and collapsible code blocks.

What i want to know is what does the code `"# In []"` mean ?

Also, within the brackets does it have to be a number or can you place text in it too ?

Kind Regards

Comment: That is a comment. It looks like someone pasted part of an ipython REPL session into a comment. It doesn't have any meaning in Python specifically, but maybe Visual Studio takes it to mean something.

Comment: as @juanpa.arrivillaga said, that's probably some typo.
As far as I know, you can make some stuff like that if you create/use code snippets extensions, other than that, it is meaningless